# package.json ignored during meteor build

Tags: meteor, npm

I upgraded my meteor project to version 1.5.1. It runs fine when I just start it with the meteor run command. But as soon as I build it, it will compain about missing babel-runtime. It seems that it ignores my package.json file in the project folder. And thus babel-runtime is not being installed when running `meteor npm install`after having built the project

Content of my package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Content of package.json inside the bundle/programs/server/ folder after running `meteor build`

```
{
  "name": "meteor-dev-bundle",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "meteor-promise": "0.8.4",
    "fibers": "1.0.15",
    "promise": "7.1.1",
    "underscore": "1.5.2",
    "source-map-support": "https://github.com/meteor/node-source-map-support/tarball/1912478769d76e5df4c365e147f25896aee6375e",
    "semver": "4.1.0",
    "node-gyp": "3.6.0",
    "node-pre-gyp": "0.6.34"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eachline": "https://github.com/meteor/node-eachline/tarball/ff89722ff94e6b6a08652bf5f44c8fffea8a21da",
    "chalk": "0.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "install": "node npm-rebuild.js"
  }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Of course I ran `meteor npm install --save babel-runtime` many times...

Comment: Have a look at this comment: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6521#issuecomment-198165040

Comment: interesting. Is it common practise to checkin node_modules into source control?

Comment: No, of course not. Though, you can add npm shrinkwrap file into your repo.

Comment: can you give me some steps I need to do to get this working. I will mark it as the solution then. I run npm shrinkwrap and added it to vc. on the remote server I do the following steps: 1. checkout repository, meteor build, go into programs/server, meteor npm install, then run it. But it still complains about babel-runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the solution would be to install `npm` modules *before* building production bundle (assuming you already have `babel-runtime` in your `package.json`):

```
cd <path_to_project>
meteor npm install
meteor build ...
```

Built bundle's `package.json` won't have `babel-runtime`, but it will be included in bundle from `node_modules` folder.

**Added:**

Don't forget that you still have to do `npm install` in your deployed bundle, as usual.

Comment: works like a charm but also is quite "over engineered" :D